# TransactionScope error "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection" in C#

Tags: c#, transactionscope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.Net TransactionScope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470512/asp-net-transactionscope-error)

whenever I put TransactionScope, I got this error.

**ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. 
The connection's current state is closed.**

```
   using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
   {

        ptDA.UpdateTC(InboundDS);
        ptDA.Addinventor(InboundDS);
        addressDA.AddAddress(InboundDS);
        scope.Complete();
  }
```

If I don't put the transaction scope , I don't get any error. This one runs well.

```
        ptDA.UpdateTC(InboundDS);
        ptDA.Addinventor(InboundDS);
        addressDA.AddAddress(InboundDS);
```

What's wrong with my transactionScope?

Comment: We need to see some more code, particularly where the connection associated with the dataadapters is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your connection within the TransactionScope.