# asp.Net TransactionScope error

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactionscope

Here is my coding

```
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (DataAccess.Document Access = new DataAccess.Document())
        {
            if (toSave.Document.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                 Access.SaveDocument(docToSave);
            }
            if (toUpdate.Document.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                 Access.UpdateEachDocument(docToUpdate);
            }
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
```

here is the error

**ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.**

Document is a class and there are save and update document methods there.

```
If I comment the transactionScope, I get no errors.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: what is the database here? what does your data access code look like (the bit that actually talks to the DB)?

Comment: You need to add connection code here.

Comment: you need to frame the question better seems same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305024/transactionscope-error-executenonquery-requires-an-open-and-available-connectio

Comment: @MarcGravell - the database is MS SQL

Comment: @V4Vendetta - Yes I ask the same question may be one month ago. I forget to check it.

Comment: My issue is If I don't use transaction, there is no error. The error only shows up when I put transactionScope.

Comment: @kevin and the last time you asked it, you were **also** asked for more of the actual database-centric code... we can't diagnose *anything* by looking at the higher levels.

Comment: Also: SQL Server **version** may be important. SQL Server 2000 uses `TransactionScope` in a very different way to SQL Server 2008, for example

Comment: In fact, our company use our own Data Access library and I also don't has access to this library.
I use Sql server 2008.

Comment: @kevin then in all honesty, I suggest you escalate this to whoever *does* have access. There's nothing we can diagnose without indicative  data access code

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is clearly saying what is wrong here. You need to put your access layer outside or commit call inside to use connection. When it is trying to commit trans in your code, it is disposed before getting there.

```
 using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (DataAccess.Document Access = new DataAccess.Document())
    {
        if (toSave.Document.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
             Access.SaveDocument(docToSave);
        }
        if (toUpdate.Document.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
             Access.UpdateEachDocument(docToUpdate);
        }
      scope.Complete();       
   }

}
```